# HP laptop, how to switch between function keys and hotkeys WITHOUT rebooting and editing BIOS setting?

Tags: windows, laptop, hotkeys, function-keys

Does anyone know of any way of switching fn key behaviour on my HP laptop (Win 10) WITHOUT having to change the setting in the BIOS? (There are no other keys on my keyboard with any reference to "fn").

Could this be done with some code or does the fact that the only current option is via the BIOS preclude this possibility?

Thanks
al

Comment: What do you mean by "switching"?

Comment: I mean toggling quickly between the two modes of function key behaviour.

Comment: Please list the fn functions that you are looking to toggle.

Comment: All of them! I just want to be able to change the default behaviour of the function keys (either fn1-12 or hotkeys, using the "fn" key in conjunction with each function/hotkey to produce the non-default action) without having to change the BIOS setting and/or reboot.

Comment: You could use a key-mapper such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to do the mapping. I can help with that, but you need to be very specific about all 12 keys.

Comment: Seems like a useful utility - with a sizeable learning curve!

Comment: So, could it be set up to, on a certain key combination, toggle _all 12_ of the function keys between defaulting as f1-f12 or brightness, media controls, etc.
eg If I'm working with, say, Excel, I'd want f1-f12 to be the default for each fn button whereas if I'm working with media files I'd prefer the media controls (etc - as laid out on the keyboard) to be the default action.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L5uMRGpcV64iS-pqrV4VHn2Sdwl-udqG/view?usp=sharing) (Picture)

Comment: AutoHotkey can do everything, but it requires some work, and most importantly - knowing what key-codes these keys generate on your computer.

Comment: Sounds good. So, how can I acquire the knowledge of these key-codes?

Comment: See [Hotkeys - Definition & Usage](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).